# How to add in ExtendedWebBrowser into toolbox?

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm currently developing an automate system which require ExtendedWebBrowser control. I have found many sample code that using ExtendedWebBrowser. But now i want to develop it by myself. I don't know how to add in ExtendedWebBrowser control as the picture below. Anyone know about it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the toolbox and select choose items menu, and select the assembly you want to add from the browsing dialog. You can create custom tabs also.

Comment: hi vs dev, i'm not sure what assembly to add in in order to get ExtendedWebBrowser control. So what's tat?